# How to deal with users who do not seem to like you?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, users

On Stack Overflow, there's many times when I've asked a question and it's been "trolled" by another user who seems to have a habit of disliking my activities. I believe this should not be permitted among Stack Overflowians, especially since some of these people have a high reputation in the department I'm commonly working in.

I'm mainly getting aggravated from the sarcasm coming from these users, and I don't know how to deal with it properly without making myself look like an ass. People usually say to just ignore it and brush it off, but this case has slowly worked its way into personal. These users just seem to always want to get the last word in, and make it as sarcastic and degrading as possible.

In the end, how should one on Stack Overflow deal with another person who has a tendency to hate you?

Comment: The comments on that question are really poor evidence that Ken hates you. If you think you see a pattern made up of comments a bit... tarter... than these, I suggest flagging them for moderator attention. No sense in making this kind of thing public. But these (two, at last view) comments are in no way rude or disgraceful.

Comment: I didn't see any sarcasm in that example... Do you have other examples?

Comment: I could make a list of examples from the same user but I don't want to and that's not the key of my question. The question is, if a particular user seems to have a direct dislike of your activities throughout time, how should you deal with them?

Comment: Well, looking back through your last 5 questions, that is the only one he has commented on. If he's very active in the Delphi tag, it could just be coincidence that he keeps running across your questions. I think you might just be over-reacting to a comment meant to be genuinely helpful.

Comment: I've been here for almost a couple years, and have asked over 200 questions. From the beginning it's been an issue. But generally, I don't mean my particular issue, that's just an example.

Comment: It is very common to run into the same user if you stay on the same tag long enough. And it is also not strange if they comment on your post and point out something you missed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've reviewed the account of the user you've cited.  Here's what I found:

1. You both work in the Delphi tag.  It's not unreasonable that you both would encounter the same questions and answers.
2. He posts comments to other user's posts that are materially similar to the ones he posts on yours.
3. His comments appear to be helpful, informative and polite.

If he responds to one of your posts again, my best advice would be to respond with "Thanks for the advice," and leave it at that.

Answer (score 3):

Just let it be. Remember the [Usenet primer](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/usenet/primer/part1)'s admonition to never forget there is a human at the other end, who might be cross because of a cold and gets offended for no real reason; and [Postel's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle), *Be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others*.